# after generating code of UML class diagram there is no override keyword before function in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, uml, class-diagram, overriding

In my UML class diagram I have a class that inherits from an abstract class and I overridden one of functions in child class from stereo type property but after generating code there is no override keyword before function definition.
is there any way to do that and I don't know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer and that was so simple, In child class if set `Is Leaf` property of function most be overridden to `True` during code generating procedure, Visual Studio excepts stereo type inheritance property.

In another word function can't be leaf and overridden in same time.